# Angular 2 ng2-charts doenst seem to work with Angular 2 RC 6 AoT Compiler

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-services, ng2-charts

I have recently upgraded my project to Angular 2 RC 6 and trying Angular 2 RC 6 AoT compilation.

In my project I am using ng2-charts (https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts) but now when I try to compile my project with Angular 2 Ahead of Time Compilation (AoT) using **ngc** it throws below error:

```
Error: Unexpected value 'CHART_DIRECTIVES' declared by the module 'AppModule'
```

Can anyone please guide how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

`ng2-chart` hasn't been switched to the new way to deploy Angular apps: [ngModules](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html).  The latest commit to the Master branch source code was [5 months ago](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/tree/master); Angular has changed a lot in that span.

My guess is `ng2-chart` library just needs to be updated.  Here is one point from the [Angular 2 rc 6 change log](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

> previously deprecated @Component.directives and @Component.pipes support was removed. All the components and pipes now must be declared via an NgModule.

`ng2-charts` depend on these directives, including the `CHART_DIRECTIVES` that triggered your error.

Comment: is there any sort of work around?  this still seems to be an issue?